# Combing two data frames by group with differing number of observations in r

Tags: r, data-binding, merge

I have two data frames. The first data frame has three variables ID, Latitude, and Longitude and has a length of 368. The second has three variables ID, Date, and value and a length of 3,058,478. Each ID has multiple observations per day and has 10 years of daily measurements in the second data set.

```
   DT1:                                  DT2: 
           ID    Latitude  Longitude            ID       Date        value
           1     38.2     -121.1                1       2000-01-01    3.1
           1     38.0     -123.1                1       2000-01-01    3.1
           1     33.8     -118.1                1       2000-01-01    3.1 
           1     34.9     -117.1                1       2000-01-01    3.8
           1     32.6     -117.1                1       2000-01-01    4.3
           1     37.6     -119.1                10      2000-01-01    3.2
          10     38.3     -121.1                10      2000-01-01    3.6
          10     39.8     -122.1                10      2000-01-01    1.2
          10     37.9     -122.1                10      2000-01-01    3.6
          10     39.5     -122.1                10      2000-01-01    1.1
          10     38.3     -122.1
```

I would like to take the first 5 observations for ID 1 from DT1 and merge them with DT2 for ID 1 and repeat that for all the IDs in DT2.  The number of observations for each ID in DT1 will be equal or greater than the number of observations for ID in DT2. Each time there is a ID in DT1 with more observations I would only like to select the top n observations that match the number of observations in DT2. DT2 will have to be grouped by Date and ID and then the Latitude and Longitude measurements can be column-binded to that grouping to get this end result:

```
End result:
     ID   Date        value   Latitude Longitude
     1    2000-01-01  3.1      38.2    -121.1
     1    2000-01-01  3.1      38.0    -123.1
     1    2000-01-01  3.1      33.8    -118.1
     1    2000-01-01  3.8      34.9    -117.1
     1    2000-01-01  4.3      32.6    -117.1
    10    2000-01-01  3.2      38.3    -121.1
    10    2000-01-01  3.6      39.8    -122.1
    10    2000-01-01  1.2      37.9    -122.1
    10    2000-01-01  3.6      39.5    -122.1
    10    2000-01-01  1.1      38.3    -122.1
```

Data:

```
  DT2<-structure(list(Date = structure(c(10957, 10957, 10957, 
  10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 
  10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 
  10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957
   ), class = "Date"), value = c(3.1, 3.1, 3.1, 3.8, 4.3, 
   3.2, 3.6, 1.2, 3.6, 1.1, 2.6, 3.8, 1.7, 4.8, 2.5, 1.7, 2.2, 2.8, 
  2.8, 1.8, 2.8, 3, 2.9, 3.6, 2, 2.4, 2.3, 3.4, 5.3, 5),ID = c("1", 
  "1", "1", "1", "1", "10", "10", "10", "10", "10", "1001", "1001", 
 "1001", "1001", "1001", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1002", "1002", 
  "1003", "1003", "1003", "1003", "1003", "1004", "1004", "1004", 
  "1004", "1004")), row.names = c(NA, 
  -30L), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), groups = structure(list(
   Date = structure(c(10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 10957, 
   10957), class = "Date"), ID = c("1", "10", "1001", 
    "1002", "1003", "1004"), .rows = list(1:5, 6:10, 11:15, 16:20, 
    21:25, 26:30)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", 
    "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE))

   DT1<-structure(list(ID = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 10, 10, 10, 10, 
    10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1001, 1002, 
    1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1002, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 1003, 
    1003, 1003, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004, 1004), 
    Latitude = c(38.201852, 37.97231, 33.821353, 34.895007, 32.631231, 
    37.64571, 38.725282, 35.385574, 38.558228, 34.421389, 37.138333, 
    38.0313, 37.7603, 33.747236, NA, 37.535833, 32.952124, 37.482934, 
    39.338504, 37.226862, 35.1019, 39.202935, 38.006311, 34.17605, 
    33.127711, 37.950741, 37.7481, 37.9642, 36.69676, 33.67464, 
    38.654069, 38.66121, 32.79222, 37.8375, 37.07206, 36.314399, 
    34.10374, 34.448048, 37.9604, 40.776944, 37.7478, 33.9397, 
    39.166017), Longitude = c(-120.681567, -122.520004, -117.91427, 
   -117.024484, -117.059075, -118.96652, -120.821916, -119.015009, 
   -121.492981, -119.701111, -119.266667, -122.1318, -122.1925, 
   -115.820124, NA, -121.961823, -117.264088, -122.20337, -120.171291, 
   -121.979675, -115.7767, -122.017728, -121.641918, -118.31712, 
    -117.075325, -121.268523, -119.5917, -122.3403, -121.637182, 
    -117.92568, -122.901857, -121.73269, -115.56306, -119.45, 
    -122.00764, -119.64457, -117.62914, -119.231321, -122.356811, 
    -124.1775, -119.5917, -115.4108, -120.148833)), row.names = c(NA, 
     -43L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can `slice` after grouping by 'ID' and then do an rbind or bind_rows

```
library(dplyr)
DT2 %>% 
     ungroup %>% 
     count(ID) %>%
    right_join(DT1 %>% 
             mutate(ID = as.character(ID))) %>%
             group_by(ID) %>%
             slice(seq_len(first(n))) %>% 
             select(-n) %>%
    bind_cols(DT2 %>%
               ungroup %>% 
               select(-ID))
#Joining, by = "ID"
# A tibble: 30 x 5
# Groups:   ID [6]
   ID    Latitude Longitude Date       value
   <chr>    <dbl>     <dbl> <date>     <dbl>
 1 1         38.2     -121. 2000-01-01   3.1
 2 1         38.0     -123. 2000-01-01   3.1
 3 1         33.8     -118. 2000-01-01   3.1
 4 1         34.9     -117. 2000-01-01   3.8
 5 1         32.6     -117. 2000-01-01   4.3
 6 10        38.7     -121. 2000-01-01   3.2
 7 10        35.4     -119. 2000-01-01   3.6
 8 10        38.6     -121. 2000-01-01   1.2
 9 10        34.4     -120. 2000-01-01   3.6
10 10        37.1     -119. 2000-01-01   1.1
# … with 20 more rows
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! The number of observations in DT2 changes per group. It isn't always 5 sometimes it can be 4 or 6. How would I modify the above code to account for that?

Comment: @Sara Can you tell me how you are determining the `n`.  Do you need a function

Comment: @Sara Please check the update if that is what you wanted

Comment: The data I provided was the top 30 observations and it just so happened that there were 5 observations for each ID but in my full data there could be anywhere from 4 to 6 per group.

Comment: @Sara `slice_head` will take 5 rows if there are 5 or more per group.  If it is less, then it takes the max number of rows

Comment: @Sara You can check that with `head(mtcars, 3) %>% slice_head(n = 5)` i subset 3 rows and apply `slice_head` with n = 5.  here, it returns 3 rows

Comment: I think that slice_head will work! When I run the code that you first provided it returns a data frame with the correct variables but Date and value are NA for all observations.

Comment: @Sara I did go through your description.  If you want the 'DT1' to be subset based on the count of ID correspondign in DT2, the update should work

Comment: I just tried the update and I am getting the correct variables in the new data frame but there are all missing values for Date and value.

Comment: @Sara I updated with `bind_cols`.  Please check the output now

Comment: I get Error: Can't recycle `..1` (size 470) to match `..2` (size 3058478).

Comment: @Sara can you show the error.  Isn't the size of DT2 with 5 rows each for each ID

Comment: @Sara how many rows you get from here `DT2 %>% 
     ungroup %>% 
     count(ID) %>%
    right_join(DT1 %>% 
             mutate(ID = as.character(ID))) %>%
             group_by(ID) %>%
             slice(seq_len(first(n))) %>% 
             select(-n)`

Comment: Yes, DT2 is 4 to 6 observations per group total data has the length of 3,058,478. DT1 has the length of 362. When I run that code I get 3058840 rows.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228801/discussion-between-sara-and-akrun).